# Using RDS Proxy IAM authentication for AWS Glue connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-glue

Is there a way to connect with RDS using RDS Proxy IAM authentication from AWS Glue connection ?
For AWS Glue connection as I know it required JDBC URL, Username and password.
But in case of RDS proxy IAM authentication it should require only Proxy JDBC URL and username only, and password should not be needed.

Because for IAM authentication it requires to generate DB auth token.

Any help on this would be appreciated to understand if its possible.